# In python 3, how to inject a function so that subsequent imports would work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Here is my code:

```
def call_it():
  from foo import bar
  bar()

def inject_it(module_name,func_name,func_def):
  #question: how to implement this function?
  pass

def main():
  def my_injected_func():
    print('hello from my_injected_func')
  inject_it('foo','bar',my_injected_func)
  call_it()
main()
```

my question is:  how to implement the 'inject_it' function above?

Comment: Does `call_it` have to work *exactly* that way? This is trivial if you can instead just use a parameter (functions are objects! you can pass them as arguments!) or a function attribute (just reset the value), or a global. Otherwise I'm not sure it's possible, and it's very deep magic if it is.

Comment: `setattr(__import__(module_name), func_name, func_def)` perhaps?

Comment: That said, you should be aware that modules imports are cached, so `foo` is only imported once, and `from foo import bar` really just *ensures that foo is imported*, then looks it up in the module cache and binds the name `bar`. So you might as well just do the import globally, and replace the global `bar`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the example above is a very simple example to the system that i am trying to modify. I cant call the functionality directly, only though import. more specifically, its an rpc server that runs command by calling import on the 'function name' part of the input

Comment: @jasonharper, i just tried it, and it didn't work..

Comment: Does the server documentation say anything about allowing for this kind of injection? What happened when you tried replacing the underlying `foo.py` file ahead of time?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the server is very sparse about documentation, it just listens to incoming socket request, which specify which function to run based on import path, executes the function and sends the results back. so far, nothing worked other than defining the function the regular way